# train.py: error: the following arguments are required: exp_name

Tags: python, tensorflow, parsing, deep-learning, arguments

I am trying to train my model where I need to pass these arguments. `exp_name` is already parsed after importing `argparse`. But it is showing an error saying that `exp_name` is required again:

> train.py: error: the following arguments are required: exp_name

Can anyone solve this issue?

**Code**:

```py
def main():
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('exp_name', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--secret_size', type=int, default=20)
    parser.add_argument('--num_steps', type=int, default=140000)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=.0001)
    parser.add_argument('--l2_loss_scale', type=float, default=1.5)
    parser.add_argument('--l2_loss_ramp', type=int, default=20000)
    parser.add_argument('--l2_edge_gain', type=float, default=10.0)
    parser.add_argument('--l2_edge_ramp', type=int, default=20000)
    parser.add_argument('--l2_edge_delay', type=int, default=60000)
    parser.add_argument('--lpips_loss_scale', type=float, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--lpips_loss_ramp', type=int, default=20000)
    parser.add_argument('--secret_loss_scale', type=float, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--secret_loss_ramp', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--G_loss_scale', type=float, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--G_loss_ramp', type=int, default=20000)
    parser.add_argument('--borders', type=str, choices=['no_edge','black','random','randomrgb','image','white'], default='black')
    parser.add_argument('--y_scale', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--u_scale', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--v_scale', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--no_gan', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_trans', type=float, default=.1)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_bri', type=float, default=.3)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_noise', type=float, default=.02)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_sat', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_hue', type=float, default=.1)
    parser.add_argument('--contrast_low', type=float, default=.5)
    parser.add_argument('--contrast_high', type=float, default=1.5)
    parser.add_argument('--jpeg_quality', type=float, default=25)
    parser.add_argument('--no_jpeg', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_trans_ramp', type=int, default=10000)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_bri_ramp', type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_sat_ramp', type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_hue_ramp', type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument('--rnd_noise_ramp', type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument('--contrast_ramp', type=int, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument('--jpeg_quality_ramp', type=float, default=1000)
    parser.add_argument('--no_im_loss_steps', help="Train without image loss for first x steps", type=int, default=500)
    parser.add_argument('--pretrained', type=str, default=None)
    args = parser.parse_args(args)

    EXP_NAME = args.exp_name
```

Comment: Could you show how you called the program?  That is, can we see how you typed out the arguments?

Comment: Thanks for your response but i changed it to parser.add_argument('--exp_name', type=str). Now its working.